# Duality while studying properties of an ensemble

Tags: brownian-motion

Was Einstein the first to propose that observing an ensemble of $N$ particles for time interval of $dt$ is same as observing a single particle of ensemble for time interval of $Ndt$?

Comment: as far as I can see this http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/files/eins_brownian.pdf is the vindication of brownian motions being due to atoms, and this historical overview https://briankoberlein.com/2015/05/05/shake-rattle-and-roll/  would argue that it was the first time. btw I was not aware of this important contribution of Einstein that resolved an a hundred year controversy. But this  belongs to history of science.